# Difference of integral limits

Tags: inequality, indefinite-integrals

We have two equations with well defined integrals:

$$\int_{a_1}^{b_1}f(x)dx = c, \ \ \int_{a_2}^{b_2}f(x)g(x)dx = c,$$

where $f(x)$ is continous, decreasing and positive while $g(x)$ is continuous, increasing and positive functions, $0\leq a_1,b_2,a_2,b_2 < \infty$ with $b_1>a_1$ and $b_2>a_2$, and $c>0$ is some constant.

If $g(x)>1$ for any $x$, can we conclude that

$$b_1 - a_1 > b_2-a_2?$$

> Attempt: If we replace $g(x)$ with any constant greater than $1$, the inequality holds. I am not sure whether such line of argument suffices.

Comment: Is $f(x)$ increasing ? Is $g(x)$ not necessarily continuous ? Can $g(x)$ be "Positive Constant" ?

Comment: @Prem edited the OP

Answer (score 1):

(A) No , **we can not conclude that** , in general.

(B) In case, we change it slightly , we can try something like that.

---

(A) Consider $f(x)=e^{-x}$ :
Integrating, we get $C=e^{-1.0}-e^{-1.1}$ between Initial Interval $1.0$ & $1.1$

Shown in the Picture, the RED Area is $C$ between Interval $1.0$ & $1.1$ , while the BLUE Area is also $C$ over larger Interval & GREEN Area is also $C$ with even larger Interval.

[image: E POWER NEGATIVE X]

To get the same $C$ further in the curve, we require longer interval.

Scaling with $g(x)=1.1,10,100,1000,$ , we can make the area below $f(x)g(x)$ arbitrarily large & we can reduce the interval required to get $C$ when moving further away from the RED Area.

Scaling with very high value , we can eventually make the New Interval EQUAL to Initial Interval, yet having same Area.
Scaling with very even higher value , we can eventually make the New Interval SMALLER than Initial Interval, yet having same Area.

**In Other words, given the Initial Interval of length 0.1, we can get the New Interval of length 100, 10, 1, 0.1, 0.01 or 0.001 , yet having Same Area.**

---

(B) Changing the Condition to state the the Initial Interval (for $f(x)$) & the New Interval (for $f(x)g(x)$) have same Starting Point, with no restriction on Ending Point.

We can now claim that the Initial Interval is SMALLER than the New interval.

[[ **Proof :** All values at all Points in the New Interval have larger (Scaling $f(x)$ by $g(x)$) values.

[image: SCALING]

Shown in Picture, the Initial Interval where RED Area & BLUE Area (below $f(x)$) have total Area $C$ , while the New Interval with Common Starting Point has RED Area & GREEN Area (below $f(x)g(x)$) have same Area $C$ .
With Starting Point same, we require shorter Interval to get same Area. ]]

To make things "uncomplicated", we can take $g(x)$ a function which Starts at $K-1$ and gradually moves to $K$ in the limit, where $K$ is some Constant.
Eg $g(x)=K-e^{-x}$
In our Discussions, we can then remove $g(x)$ & use Constant $K$